# What am I missing here by using AWSSDK.Lambda.AmazonLambdaClient without response

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm using the following code

```
var options = new AmazonLambdaConfig
 {
     RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1,
     Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
 };

 var client = new Amazon.Lambda.AmazonLambdaClient("KEY", "SECRET", options);
 
 client.ExceptionEvent += Client_ExceptionEvent;
 client.AfterResponseEvent += Client_AfterResponseEvent;
 client.BeforeRequestEvent += Client_BeforeRequestEvent;
 string _awsResult = string.Empty;
 Console.WriteLine("2");


 var payload = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
 {
     client = "CLIENT",// client
     version = "2.0",
     action = "getData",
     serialNumber = System.Convert.ToBase64String("00-0A-40-97-0D-17".HexStringToHex()),// serial
 });
 Console.WriteLine("3");

 var response = await client.InvokeAsync(new Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeRequest
 {
     FunctionName = "FUNCTIONNAME-XYZ",
     Payload = payload,
 });
```

It is running as a .net6  console application.
On five machines in production and also on two other developer machines without any problems. On one machine I got no response after calling InvokeAsync.

I started a new project with .net Framework 4.7.2. The same code, same nuget-packages. It runs perfect and like expected.

This here are the nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.7.204" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Lambda" Version="3.7.201.49" />
```

The required .net 6 Desktop runtime is also installed.

I'm realy confused and have no idea what's going wrong here.

**UPDATE**

I created two test applications. One as .net6 and the other .net framework 4.7.2. Here you can see... the .net6 is not working like the fw 4.7.2.

[image]

A test with CLI was also successfull:
[image]

Comment: Are the machines in production EC2 instances? Are they all in the same VPC? Can you call the lambda from the faulty machine using the CLI: `aws lambda invoke --function-name=FUNCTIONNAME-XYZ --payload = '{...}'`? When the app calls the lambda from the faulty machine, are there any CloudWatch logs generated?

Comment: I have no direct access to this function on aws. I got only credentials and the functionname. All machines are in the same VPC. It's crazy... same machine but with net framework 4.7. application is working!

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "I have no direct access to this function on aws"? Is the faulty machine an EC2 instance? Can you log in there and run this command?

Comment: It's a physical machine. A Microsoft Surface Tablet with Win 11.

Comment: Can you run the command I posted? `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=[KEY] AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=[SECRET] aws lambda invoke --function-name=FUNCTIONNAME-XYZ --payload='{...}'`

Comment: I got it localy on my own machine. I can check the faulty machine tomorrow cause factory is closed for today :-( Thank you! I will try and give you feedback.

Comment: I can call your command on the faulty machine. Output is json
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}

Comment: Underneath your Lambda call there's just an http request which cannot complete. Something is apparently wrong with your .net6 installation: probably a Windows firewall setting, or something. Given that the other machines work, I would say it's not a programming problem anymore.